# Unwanted Char Appears Giving Url to Images

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I have images in this order : [image][image]

When i give each of them an url, - char suprisingly appears between them.I don't understand why - appears.

Here is the code :

```
<div style='float:left;  width:320px;'>
                <span>
                     <a href='http://www.boun.edu.tr'/>
                     <img style='width:75px; height:75px' src='$img_root/logo_bogaz.jpg' alt='logo bogazici university'> 
                </span>
                <span>
                     <a href='http://www.gyte.edu.tr'/>
                     <img style='width:70px; height:70px' src='$img_root/gyte.gif'    alt='logo gyte'>  
                </span>
</div>
```

And OUTPUT :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of the underline from your anchor tag. You can remove the underline as per below. (Note this will remove it for all links)

Add this to fix:

```
<style>
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
```

Ideally this should go in a separate CSS file. But add it to the top of your HTML for an easy test.